# How to change user's permissions under django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on Geonode and when I add a new layer, people who are not logged in are not suppose to see the layers but I would like to change it and allow it to everyone. I saw on an old forum that it was possible by changing the SKIP_PERMS_FILTER in a file and the read_list too, but I am not use to django and I don't know what to change.

```
SKIP_PERMS_FILTER = strtobool(os.getenv('SKIP_PERMS_FILTER', 'False'))
```

```
def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        permitted_ids = get_objects_for_user(
            bundle.request.user,
            'base.view_resourcebase').values('id')

        return object_list.filter(id__in=permitted_ids)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem and just had to delete the `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` statement in the code just before the function who is suppose to print the layers.